# IE9 <tr>'s won't overflow-y issue

Tags: internet-explorer-9, overflow

I've got a table where the `thead` is static and `tbody` has an `overflow-y: scroll`. This works in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10+ but it doesn't work in IE 9. I know this issue can be fixed for lists by adding `display: inline-block`; but this doesn't apply to tables. Please help!

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>Header</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>test</tr>
        <tr>test</tr>
        <tr>test</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```